# laravel route points to the right view but doesn't change the link in the address bar

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have this situation:

```
Route::get('/Page/view1,'SomeController@showform');
Route::post('/Page/view1,'SomeController@store');
```

In the showform method:

```
Return view(’/Page/view1’);
```

In view1.blade.php there is a form which sends data to `SomeController@store`. I even icluded this `{!!Form::open([’url’=>’/Page/view1’, ’method’=>’POST’])!!}` although it’s nout necessay because by default the method is ’POST’

In `SomeController@store` there is a condition:

```
If (condition)
Return view(’Page/view2’);
```

The condition is met and I see view2 on the screen. However, in the address bar I see **/Page/view1**

Am I missing something ?(I'm quite new to laravel)

Answer (score 1):

You have one adress (`Page/view1`) but two ways to enter to this link. You can go by GET (and you will see view `Page/view1`) or you can go by POST (and you will se view `Page/view2`) but adress is the same :)

It's like two doors - on the left to **ROOM1** and on the right to **ROOM2** but labels on this doors are the same, for simple *Enter here*. I hope it helps ;)

Comment: The logic behind is intact... I have no problem with this. But in some cases, users may share the link to that page. Even though the page shows what it should show, the link in the address bar is wrong and the users who will click it will be pointed to somewhere else. Is there any way of making laravel show the right view? In the situation that I mentioned, I would like to see /Page/view2 when view2 is loaded...

Comment: You can try to use Route::any(). This redirect any routes to your controller. But I think you should use GET parameters if you want to create share links.